# Communications problem between esp32 and AD5763

Tags: dac, esp32

I am trying to make huzzah32 (ESP32) communicate with AD5763 but I am having some problems with writing and reading in registers.
I am sure that the bit sequences I send are actually the ones I wanted (I checked them with the oscilloscope).

What I'm trying to do is reading and writing of a register.
To do this I send these three commands in sequence:

```
// writing
00010001 00001111 00001111
// reading
10010001 00000000 00000000
// nop
00000000 00000000 00000000
```

In response to the nop, I would expect to receive the values ​​that I wrote in the director, so something like this:

```
10010001 00001111 00001111
```

but instead I always get a copy of the read command:

```
 10010001 00000000 0000000000
```

I tried to read several registers and each time it returns the copy of the command.
By setting the SDO-Disable command I actually see that the DAC does not respond to me or not, depending on the disabling\enabling.

To be more precise and complete the setup information, I use this PINs configuration:

- sync-negate: LOW during the communication, HIGH otherwise
- clr-negate: HIGH
- ldac-negate: LOW
- rstin-negate: HIGH
- miso / mosi: for the communications

Anyone have any idea what it could be?

## SUPPLEMENTARY INFORMATION

- The code I'm using: https://github.com/XaBerr/AD5763-firmware
- Huzzah32 datasheet: https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-huzzah32-esp32-feather.pdf
- AD5763 datasheet: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5763.pdf

Comment: Please include a timing diagram or screenshot of what you are seeing on your scope. It's pretty much impossible to tell you anything without seeing timing and which lines are doing what.

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the data MSB first?  Did you negate SYNC* between sending the read command and the additional clocks to actually read the data?

Comment: You're probably going to need to include the code.  Another thing you can do is grab a resistor in the 1-10K range and use it to pull MISO and see if at least *that* is reflected in your results.

Comment: @crj11 Yes, I'm sure I'm sending MSB because I can see from the oscilloscope the right order. Yes, I'm sending the additionals clock to read the data because this is the NOP operation. Yes, I see in the oscilloscope the sync signal to go down during the communication.

Comment: @David as soon as I have the oscilloscope available I take the photo

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't think the code could help so much because the messages I'm programming with the code I see them with the oscilloscope, so the code is working as intended. Probably the problem is or the device or the sequences that I'm sending.

Comment: I'm unconvinced it's not a code problem with the SPI.  If you get different behavior on MISO with a scope by not enabling the SPI select and confirm with a resistor that you are reading the actual state of MISO then might be ready to believe that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've added a SUPPLEMENTARY INFORMATION section where I've linked the code